# Header data overwriting Post data in XMLHttpRequest

Tags: ajax, post, http-headers, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain

I'm trying to implement a file(image) upload API, given here: 

[Mediafire file Upload](http://developers.mediafire.com/index.php/REST_API#upload)

I'm using this API **from client-side** so that file only needs to be uploaded once and server bandwidth is not used for large files. Uploading thru client side also saves time.

**My web hosting service has restriction on execution time and bandwidth.*

As of now, Im **successfully** able to send the *GET* & *POST* parameters as given in above API, and the file is being **uploaded in my mediafire account**. However it is impossible to receive the response due to [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

**Javascript Code:**

```
var url = "http://www.mediafire.com/api/upload/upload.php?"+"session_token="+getCookie("mSession")+"&action_on_duplicate=keep";

xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
     if(xmlhttp.readyState==4)
     {
          alert("Uploaded");
     }
}

xmlhttp.open("POST", url);

var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("Filedata", document.getElementById("myFile").files[0]);
xmlhttp.send(formData);
```

Everything is fine up to here, but, as response is not available from mediafire api, i cannot access the uploaded file anymore. However there is a workaround to access the file if **file name** is known. PS : Mediafire keeps the same name as it was on local storage, but in case if there is a file with same name in mediafire account, it is changed.

So there can be **2 solutions** :

1. rename the file before sending to above API
2. or send header data  as shown in the API

I tried the 2nd solution by adding :

```
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("x-filename", "foobar1.jpg");
```

to the above code, but it changes the form method from *POST* to *OPTIONS*, and there is no action in mediafire account(file is not uploaded).

What am I doing wrong? Is there any other way that I can control or at-least know, the name of the uploaded file in mediafire account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For **POST** request, if you give custom headers, the browsers takes preflight request(**options** instead of **POST**). If the origin allows, then browser takes POST request. refer ([cors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS))